# How do I change ;A;B;C; to ('A', 'B', 'C')?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to convert a value list separated by semi-colons, including in front, into a regular value list with quotes and commas. There might only be one value, or there may be many values in the field.

I thought about replacing the ; with a comma, but then I still have a comma in front and behind, and I also need to add single quotes.

```
REPLACE(S_List, ';', ',')
```

I want ;a;b;c; to be 'a','b','c' or at least a,b,c but I don't know what to do with the beginning and end semicolons

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Run `SELECT @@version` in SSMS.

Comment: If this is a part-way step towards e.g. trying to parameterise an `IN()` expression, realize you're going about it the wrong way. You should be working towards getting a *set* of separate values, not a *string* to force the server to parse to turn into values.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, thank you!  That is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
declare @slist varchar(100) = ';a;b;c;'
select substring(replace(@slist, ';', ''','''), 3, len(replace(@slist, ';', ''',''')) - 4)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94920fbbf0ae6f06cd80cf34e6fea64c).
Result:

```
'a','b','c'
```

**Edit**.
Use it like this in your table:

```
select 
  case when s_list like '%;%;%' then
    substring(replace(s_list, ';', ''','''), 3, len(replace(s_list, ';', ''',''')) - 4)
    else s_list
  end  
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8170b575944aa0bad28da6ca91a84b78).

Comment: There might be no values, one value, or more than 3.  A,B,C was just an example.

Comment: @rainforest So what is the problem?

Comment: In yours, it doesn't reference my column name at all

Comment: This is an example. I use the variable `@slist`. You can change it to the column's name.

Comment: I included a demo sample. All you have to do is replace @slist with your column's name. What else did you do with the answer you accepted?

Comment: I got an error.    Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: See my edited answer and the demo. This works even if you have empty values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(S_List,1),';','''')
 SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(S_List,1),';','''')

 SELECT REPLACE(S_List,';', ''',''')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values do not have spaces, you can use a `trim()` trick:

```
select '''' + replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(s_list, ',', ' '))), ',', ''',''') + ''''
```

Comment: @forpas I went with this, which was close:  REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(replace(Site_List, ';', ','), ',', ' '))), ' ', ',')